# Can an Indian citizen on B1/B2 tourist visa in the US, apply for a schengen visa in the US?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I am leaving India for the US and plan to tour Europe on my way back from the US. However, I believe I can't apply for a Schengen visa in India before leaving to Europe because I would be staying in the US for six months - longer than the validity of the schengen visa.

Thus I am curious if I can apply for a schengen visa from the US, while touring the US on a B1/B2 tourist visa.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london

Answer (score 2):

I checked a few EU embassies sites for requirements, none of them explicitly says that you will have to be a permanent resident to apply for the visa. While I am sure on other EU embassies (such as in UAE) you are required to be a citizen or a permanent resident.

Anyway, I think it is possible as many travelers especially ones who travel for long times do apply for tourist visas on the road. I also think you will face some problems though, one of them is providing a recent original copy of your employment certificate and a recent bank account statement.

Your best bet is letting someone back home email you these documents and visit a consulate with all the documents and then explain to them your situation, I guess you will get it. Remember, your stay and intend to leave the US is a positive thing and I guess it will help you in getting the Schengen visa.