# How to get schengen visa if already in UK

Tags: schengen, uk, london, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am in United Kingdom on a visit c-type.. What if I wish to visit Paris from UK.. How to get a Schengen visa on Pakistani passport?

Comment: Check the rules and regulations of the French Embassies in the UK. They are the ones issuing Schngen visas if your main country of visit is France. It is quite likely that they only allow residents of the UK to apply there, though. In that case, you are out of luck and would need to return to your home country before you can apply. Note that questions that are very similar to yours have been answered many times on this page - just use the search function.

Comment: We have tons of questions on this. Usually it's difficult but there are some exceptions, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london

Answer (score 1):

You need to re ask it -unfortunately- from Pakistan. 
French visas issued by the french ambassy in the UK are only issued to British and residents in the UK. With your C-type visa you're not considered as one.