# Can I apply for Romanian and Bulgarian transit visas from Turkey as a non-resident?

Tags: visas, romania, bulgaria, saudi-citizens

I'm a Saudi national. I will ship my bike to Turkey and travel to it by air. I will have a Turkish visa of course. I will then travel on road to Bulgaria aiming to reach Romania. Do I have to apply for visa prior to reaching there or I can get it on road from both borders? I will stay travelling for a month at the most.

Comment: Saudis need to get a visa to enter Bulgaria, and they need to apply for it beforehand.  You would be turned back if you tried asking for it at the border.  Also, you wouldn't qualify for a transit visa if you are travelling by road through the country. Same thing for Romania. So I am voting this as a duplicate.  The canonical points to the Bulgarian rules and Saudi nationals are included as a line item.

Comment: "Also, you wouldn't qualify for a transit visa if you are travelling by road through the country. Same thing for Romania."
So, do you mean that also if I get the tourist visa for both countries I can't get through on road either? 
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: All part of the service. Please be careful, you have 3 questions and 3 flags against them. You may find yourself banned.  So read the FAQ if you think the site is something you want to use on a continuous basis.

Comment: @GayotFow What do you mean with 'you need a Schengen visa'? Even if a Schengen visa with some exceptions entitles you to enter Romania and Bulgaria as well, another Schengen state is unlikely to issue a visa for travel only to Romania and/or Bulgaria (neither country is member of the Schengen area).

Comment: The alleged duplicate question does not address peculiarities of this specific situation. It could be adequate for the OP to obtain a Bulgarian visa, since he might be allowed to enter Romania on a Bulgarian visa as well. Romania allows holder of Bulgarian visas to enter, but not the other way around.

Comment: Now I'm confused a bit. @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo says I can enter with a normal visa. And (Gayot Fow) said I need a Schengen visa. Can you guys clarify more please. To enter by road, to bulgaria, should I get a Schengen visa or a normal tourist visa? 
Thank you guys for helping me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @FaisalTM I am confused as well. Instead of answering my comment, Gayot Fow seem to have just deleted his incorrect comment. Unless the question is reopened, it is not possible for me to write a proper answer. I've flagged the question. Perhaps a moderator will take a look at it.

Comment: @FaisalTM, I don't think it's confusing, you have two options: [1] get a country specific visa for Bulgaria or [2] use an existing Schengen visa issued by one of the full member states.  Either one of these will work, not sure what Tor-Einar wants to give as an answer for other options, so let's wait and see...

Answer (score 1):

[Since 1 January 2007 the Republic of Bulgaria has been applying the European Union’s Common Visa Policy, subject to the terms of the Accession Treaty](http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html). One thing that means is no distinct Transit visa (except for *airport* transit - Type `A`). So you need a Type `C`, Uniform Schengen Visa (short-term) *for a short stay for the purpose of transit or a planned stay*, unless exempt. I'm afraid Saudi nationals are [not exempt](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/Consular/050615_EN_VisaRegime_for_foreigners_ordinary_passports.pdf).

Since as not a permanent resident you may have great difficulty† (in effect, the answer to your Title question is "no", not transit, not `C`) in applying for a visa while in Turkey you may want to apply through [VFS-Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/bulgaria/saudiarabia/) in Saudi Arabia, where you may choose from a centre in Riyadh or Jeddah. You may lodge an application up to [three months in advance](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf) of the planned time of your arrival at the Bulgarian border.

For [Romania](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) you would have completed all the hard work:

> The holders of visas or residence permits issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia.

are excused a Romanian visa.

The above assumes your time in Bulgaria and Romania will be less than 90 days - and does not consider how you might be returning from Romania.

† [see](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48757/4995)

Answer (score 1):

You will only need a Bulgarian **OR** Romanian visa, **NOT** both. Apply through the country you'll be spending the most time in.

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=sa&DE=bg&DE=ro&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, about Bulgaria:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a C visa issued by
>   Croatia, Cyprus, **Romania** or a Schengen Member State
>   valid for the period of intended stay. They are
>   visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days

And for Romania:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a C visa issued by
>   Bulgaria, Croatia or Cyprus valid for the period of intended
>   stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.

Visas are only issued at the border if you need to enter for an important emergency (such as a funeral), didn't have the time to get a visa in advance, **and** can prove it.

In addition, the [Bulgarian](http://www.vfsglobal.com/bulgaria/turkey/english/) embassy requires you to be a Turkish resident. The Romanian consulate doesn't say anything on their website about this, but it may well be the same there.

As such, it is strongly recommended for you to get the visa (either Bulgarian or Romanian) before leaving Saudi