# How to apply for a Schengen visa from the UK if my visa expires in less than 90 days?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, residency, turkish-citizens

This is what Schengen countries say on their visa page

> UK residence permit (original and copy): valid for at least 90 days beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen area.

Reference : http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html

I live in the UK but need to renew my visa in about 80 days, in the meantime I need to go to a Schengen country for about 2 days. My UK visa it just taking its natural course and will be renewed at the end of this time. I've been living in the UK over 4 years now, it's just the standard procedure before moving to permanent residency.

So is there anyway for me to get a Schengen visa, can I explain this to any Schengen embassy?

Comment: Are you asking them for a concession?

Comment: @GayotFow not sure what you mean? Could you elaborate?

Comment: What is it that you want the Schengen embassy to do?

Comment: What's your country of citizenship?

Comment: @DJClayworth Turkey

Comment: @GayotFow I want them to make an exception because it's obvious that my visa will be extended by UK. I wonder if they do this regularly or not.

Comment: It's not obvious to them that your visa will be extended. Maybe your employer is about to go bankrupt, or something else will happen to prevent your visa being extended.

Comment: @DJClayworth Sure it's not but why would they care anyway. If I cannot come back to UK I'll just go back to Turkey. Why does it matter?

UK visa renewal process will also take couple of months, so I guess it's not possible for me to get a Schengen visa for 4+ months now.

Comment: Have you looked at the process for getting a visa to Germany if you didn't have a UK residence visa? That process must exist.

Comment: Yes but it seems like I need to be in Turkey to do that

Comment: @JohnDelie, the formal term for what you're doing is "seeking a concession", hence my previous comment. Anyway I doubt you'll be successful obtaining one because "renewing" a UK residence permit is NOT a mere formality. But for sure nothing prevents you from trying.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78589/why-is-it-required-to-have-a-uk-visa-valid-for-an-extra-90-days-when-applying-fo

Comment: Related up to point of me flagging as dupe: [Can Indians on UK tourist visa apply for Schengen tourist visa in London?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/48756/32134)

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this question for the benefit of people who are in the same situation and are googling for a solution, as I was.

I have written directly to the embassy, and they allowed me to apply as long as I still have one month valid on my residence permit after my return. I then explained that to Vfsglobal, the third party agency which does the visa paperwork for German visa, and was asked to attach the printout of the email from the embassy to my application documents. In the end my application was successful.

Answer (score 2):

> So is there anyway for me to get a Schengen visa, can I explain this to any Schengen embassy?

By default, no, you won't be able to. The general rule, defined in article 6 of the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018) is that

> 1. An application shall be examined and decided on by the consulate of the competent Member State in whose jurisdiction the applicant legally resides.

And since the Schengen consulates don't consider you to be a UK resident, you can't apply from London. The same article does however open another possibility, namely that

> 2. A consulate of the competent Member State shall examine and decide on an application lodged by a third-country national legally present but not residing in its jurisdiction, if the applicant has provided justification for lodging the application at that consulate.

If you can somehow convince the consular officer that you *must* travel to the Schengen area (e.g. for a funeral) and don't have the opportunity to apply in Turkey (e.g. because it's very expensive) then you might be permitted to apply in the UK. However I wouldn't rely on this to work.

Comment: "I wouldn't take my chances with this": Why not? There's no negative consequence if it doesn't succeed.

Comment: @phoog post rephrased