# Why is it required to have a UK visa valid for an extra 90 days when applying for a Schengen visa from the UK?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, spain

I have lost out on my holiday to Spain because my British visa would not have had 90 days remaining beyond my return to the UK. Therefore, I could not apply for a Schengen visa (or so I was told) and missed out on my holiday. I did not realize this rule was in place.

Why does my British visa affect a Schengen visa? I am not in a danger category whatsoever, being married to a British born and bred, and permanently living in the UK.

Comment: What's your nationality?  Also, I'm having a little difficulty reconciling "*permanently living in the UK*" with "*my British visa would not have had 90 days remaining*".  What is your current status in the UK?

Comment: To MadHatter: Ukrainian on a spouse visa. They require  that

Comment: How bizarre!  Can you get a UK passport - how long do you have to wait?  It's generally extremely easy for "real" UK citizens to get a spouse from anywhere a UK passport. I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: @JoeBlow that might have been the case once, but these days getting a spouse into the UK is not that easy. There are both time and financial barriers to getting people to permanent settlement status, let alone citizenship. Hence Surinder Singh route, etc.

Comment: that's bizarre, is it because Ukraine ?

Comment: @JoeBlow, the era of easy spouse immigration ended about 27 years ago. Do try to keep up :)

Comment: @Funtik it's about returnability. They require a valid visa extending 90 days beyond the departure from Schengen.

Comment: @Funtik If you include an @ with a username in your comment, that person will be pinged (= receive a notification in the top bar). That way, they won’t miss your comment. The post owner (in this case: you) is always pinged, so the @ with your name at the beginning of this comment is superfluous ;)

Comment: heh, hi @GayotFow - i don't get it, my best friend (UK pp) married an American girl (US pp).  they simply moved to the UK and after about 12? months, she got a UK pp (ie, citizenship + pp).  this was, oh, 10? yrs ago. Correction - I think you have to sit for 36 months (not 12 months) before she got it.  However ....

Comment: in that example when the American girl arrives in the UK, i'm pretty sure you immediately (ie a matter of days) get the paperwork (visa, whatever) where as a spouse you can just stay indefinitely (I think you have to renew it every 2 1/2 years, which is trivial).  it seems sad the OP mentions a "90 day limit" that is running out.

Comment: Hello Funtik, can you clarify if *you* or *your spouse* is the permanent resident?