# How can I apply for a Schengen visa from the UK without being a resident for 3 months?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, indian-citizens

I will be moving to the UK in August with Tier 2 long term visa. I'm an Indian passport holder. I would want to get a Schengen visa as soon as possible. How could I get one without waiting for 3 months after getting a residence permit? Is there any way to get the visa as soon I get the RP?

Comment: What makes you think you'd have to wait for months?

Comment: I don't understand what is this 3 months wait ? There is nothing that can be done to "speed up" the visa process, except maybe get a priority appointment at a third party visa processing center (like VFS, if the  country you are planning to get the visa for outsources their services).

Comment: Why do you need a Schengen visa? UK is not in the Schengen Area, and you have a separate visa to move to the UK. If you really need a Schengen visa for some reason before the 3-month term, you can apply at the relevant Schengen country's embassy or consulate in India. The 3-month limit is for applying from the UK.

Comment: To apply for a Schengen visa from the UK you must be a UK resident for at least three months.
Read more at https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-uk/#wjk4gfGZecSpdtKy.99  . I wanted to know if i can get a Schengen Visa as soon as i get Residence permit , as it says i will have to be a resident for 3 months.

Comment: The schengen visa info website seems to have the wrong information. VFS websites don't have any information as such for schengen visas and they are the 3rd party where you will file your application.

Comment: I think you have it confused. You must have at least 3 months *left* on your UK visa, not the other way around: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74275/how-to-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-from-the-uk-if-my-visa-expires-in-less-than-90

Answer (score 2):

I believe you misunderstood the visa requirements. According to [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html):

> UK residence permit (original and copy): valid for at least 90 days beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen area.

Which means you need your residency permit to be valid for at least 90 days **after** you return from the Schengen area, rather than the opposite way. So you can go ahead and apply without waiting.